# Calling a method of a static class - with the class names and the method name as strings

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a namespace with such cascaded class structure

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{

    public static class Class1
    {


        public static class Class2
        {
        
            public static class Class3
            {

                public static class Class4
                {

                    public static string MyMethod(string someinput) 
                    {
                        return "hello " + someinput;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to call the method , using its name as follows:

```
public static void Main() 
{
     
       string testinput = "test";

       // this version works
       // var targetClass = typeof(MyNameSpace.Class1.Class2.Class3.Class4);            nput });
        
       // this version wont work. How can I make it work?
       string fullClassName = "MyNameSpace.Class1.Class2.Class3.Class4";
       var targetClass = Type.GetType(fullClassName);

       // then I can call the method using its name and invoke it. 
       var targetMethod = targetClass.GetMethod("MyMethod");
       targetMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { testinput});

}
```

I however could not make this invoke work.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The runtime name of that type is actually `MyNameSpace.Class1+Class2+Class3+Class4`. Note that your code contains plenty of other errors that prevent it from running at all.

Comment: For example: `static void ... return "hello" ...`

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert for the heads up. I did my best to debug the errors.

Answer (score 0):

@jeroen Mostert, thank you.

the following code now works:

```
// You should use "+" (not ".") between the class names.
// Then you can get the type of the cascading classes that way, 
// and call the method of the target class with the method name as string and invoke it.

string fullClassName = "MyNameSpace.Class1+Class2+Class3+Class4"; 
var targetClass = Type.GetType(fullClassName);
var targetMethod = targetClass.GetMethod("MyMethod");
string testinput = "test";
targetMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] {testinput});
```